# TURN server behind reverse proxy

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, turn, coturn

I would like to make the TURN server accessible behind a reverse proxy in order to use port 443 to avoid problems with blocked ports on public wifi networks, etc.

coturn is configured this way:

```
listening-port=8443
listening-ip=127.0.0.1
relay-ip=<public-ip-of-the-turn-server>                                                        
lt-cred-mech
use-auth-secret
static-auth-secret="secret"
realm=myturnserver.org
total-quota=0
bps-capacity=0
log-file=/var/log/turn.log
```

and the apache server config looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName myturnserver.org
ServerAdmin root@myturnserver.org
DocumentRoot /var/www/html                                                                                                                

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/myturnserver.org.error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/myturnserver.org.access.log combined

SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/myturnserver.org/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/myturnserver.org/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8443/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8443/

</VirtualHost>
```

but I can't connect to the turn server. Any ideas what is wrong here?

Comment: Did you successfully connect after two years :)? I think apache does not support Turn traffic.

Comment: COTURN just added reverse proxy support in their 4.5.2r3 version (at least the first one I saw the config file talk about it). Check its turnserver.conf in the examples folder in the github for the coturn/coturn distro master. Regarding your VirtualHost in the question, you are forwarding every request to the TURN server, so letsencrypt won't be able to validate your domains ownership and not renew your certificates. Although I am not sure how this will work with SSL inside COTURN, since the STUNNEL will take care of the SSL layer. MMMmmmm, any experts to help here?